# Joining table with Command - Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I need to make a report where I need to combine Command and another table together.
How can I integrate a table in the SQL query in Command so I can have all fields and formulas from that table in Command?

The query for Command is really long and complicated and it's used in another report. I'm trying to use this Command with another table called mCallEnd because I need couple of fields from mCallEnd table to make my report.
How can I do that in SQL query?

Command is on this link: http://www.docdroid.net/13pis/command1.txt.html

Report that I need to make looks like this: [http://i.imgur.com/2boSrzJ.jpg?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVQKC.jpg)1

Answer (score 0):

Try joining command and table in crystal report database expert. Which should work... if that is not possible for you.. try below.

Create a view with that command and join the view and table in crystal reports database expert.

Above solution provided assuming command and table are in same database.